# How to switch compass version?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass, compass-sass

I have two versions of Compass, 0.12 and 0.13.alpha. The default version is 0.13.alpha but sometimes I need to switch to 0.12.

What command will permit this, please?

Comment: no need to downvote guys. looks like a legit question to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are switching versions for different projects, I recommend using either [RVM](http://rvm.io/rvm/install/) (Ruby) or [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html) with [some help](https://gist.github.com/1078601) (Python) or something similar to manage gems and versions. [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) will help make either solution simpler to maintain.

If you are switching versions within a project, I recommend reconsidering your approach.

Answer (score 3):

old topic, but I just came across the issue of having 2 projects. one using compass version `0.12` and the other `1.0`.

as the newer version of compass relies on a new major release of sass, many deprecation warnings and compatibility issues are experienced when trying to run the newer compass on the old project.

---

well, now to the solution:

ruby gems already support having multiple versions installed. and after taking a look into the `compass` executable, it turns out there is a way to specify which compass version to use (the file is generated by rubygems, see http://pastebin.com/HeZnE0T5 if you are curious)

with that we can now have multiple versions of compass installed at once. eg:

```
gem install compass -pre // currently version 1.0.0.alpha.19
gem install compass // currently version 0.12.6
```

and now we can use them by specifying which version to use:

```
$ compass version
Compass 1.0.0.alpha.19
Copyright (c) 2008-2014 Chris Eppstein
Released under the MIT License.
Compass is charityware.
Please make a tax deductable donation for a worthy cause: http://umdf.org/compass

$ compass _0.12.6_ version
Compass 0.12.6 (Alnilam)
Copyright (c) 2008-2014 Chris Eppstein
Released under the MIT License.
Compass is charityware.
Please make a tax deductable donation for a worthy cause: http://umdf.org/compass
```

this obviously also works for other compass commands, eg `watch`:

```
$ compass _0.12.6_ watch .
>>> Compass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.
```

EDIT: of course the version switch can be done in a Gemfile, but in my case its not a ruby project and compass is started via command line

Answer (score 2):

This is really simple using bundler.

Install bundler:

```
$ gem install bundler
```

Create the Gemfile in your project if you don't already have one:

```
$ bundle init
```

Specify the version you want/need in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'compass', '~>0.12.2'
gem 'sass', '3.2.8'
```

Install the specific gems and dependencies you have defined in your Gemfile:

```
$ bundle install
```

When executing a gem, you can now use bundler to control which version to execute based on your Gemfile:

```
$ bundle exec compass watch
```

That's it!

It's helpful to leave a comment in your Gemfile telling other developers how to use bundler:

```
# Now that you're using Bundler, you need to run `bundle exec compass watch` instead of simply `compass watch`.
```

Read more about versioning at http://bundler.io/v1.6/gemfile.html

Answer (score 1):

Change the gemfile, add in a version parameter.